# Git - deleted some files locally, how do I get them from a remote repository

Tags: git

I've deleted some files on my PC, how do I download them again?

Pull says: "Already up-to-date".

Comment: You don't have to "download them again," because all of the repository history exists locally when you are using Git.

Comment: do you know how to get them from local?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Since git is a distributed VCS, your local repository contains all of the information. No downloading is necessary; you just need to extract the content you want from the repo at your fingertips.

If you haven't committed the deletion, just check out the files from your current commit:

```
git checkout HEAD <path>
```

If you have committed the deletion, you need to check out the files from a commit that has them. Presumably it would be the previous commit:

```
git checkout HEAD^ <path>
```

but if it's `n` commits ago, use `HEAD~n`, or simply fire up `gitk`, find the SHA1 of the appropriate commit, and paste it in.

Comment: just as a side comment, this also works for a full directory, its not special or specific to a single file (it worked when I tried it at least). Thnx btw.

Comment: N.B. the `<path>` is mandatory, even if just `.` dot for current dir. But the "branch" (`HEAD` in the above example) is optional. As with so many Git commands, neither the output nor help is helpful.

Answer (score 49):

`git checkout filename`

`git reset --hard` might do the trick as well

Comment: warning tho in using the `git reset --hard` method as that will revert the entire tree back to w/e location you put HEAD/HEAD^/HEAD~n and it will do it w/o prejudice and potentially lose a lot of commits...

Comment: git checkout filename was the answer for me :)

Comment: git checkout filename creates just an empty file

Comment: placed in the desired folder and did `git checkount .` worked like a charm!

Comment: git checkout filename is awesome!

Answer (score 32):

If you deleted multiple files locally and did not commit the changes, go to your local repository path, open the git shell and type.

```
$ git checkout HEAD .
```

All the deleted files before the last commit will be recovered.

Adding "." will recover all the deleted the files in the current repository, to their respective paths.

For more details checkout the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

Answer (score 27):

If you have deleted multiple files locally but not committed, you can force checkout

```
$ git checkout -f HEAD
```

Comment: As we see from the output "Already up-to-date", the person asking this question has not committed anything lately.
Should you maybe specify that git checkout -f HEAD is DANGEROUS?
As it might undo local changes that were not commited (restoring previous files being the positive outcome, losing changes on edited files the negative one).

Comment: Keep in mind that this command will overwrite all your local changes.

Answer (score 5):

In the code directory: `git checkout .`

Answer (score 4):

If your deleted file(s) is already staged, `git checkout <file>` doesn't work.

You have to unstage first and then do checkout

To unstage

```
git restore --staged <file>
```

and then do checkout

```
git checkout <file>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check out a previous version from before you deleted the files. Try `git checkout HEAD^` to checkout the last revision.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather niche use-case (although funnily enough answers the question as stated exactly), but just in case anyone ever needs this: if you do `git filter-branch` removing a file along with its history and then you want to recover just the latest versions of the removed files, `git checkout filename` won't be enough (because the file is no longer in the local history of the repository) and you need to specify that you want to reset to the remote version using `git checkout origin/main -- filename`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, I add to do the following steps so that the git repo would be correctly linked with the IDE:

```
 $ git reset <commit #>

 $ git checkout <file/path>
```

I hope this was helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

If the removal was not yet committed: Identify removed files with

```
git status
```

and then restore them from local index by

```
git restore <file>
```

("To discard changes in working directory" as documentation says).